# Ajax 400 error after Express Validator runs server-side validation

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, express-validator

I am trying to fix a form handler that always throws a 400 error after middleware validation.

The middleware validation goes like this:

```
const contactValidate = [
  check('name')
    .exists()
    .trim()
    .escape()
    .not()
    .isEmpty()
    .withMessage('Name can not be empty!')
    .bail()
    .isLength({min: 2})
    .withMessage('Minimum 2 characters required!')
    .bail()
    .isAlpha('en-US', {ignore: ' '})
    .withMessage('Name can only have letters and spaces')
    .bail(),
  check('phone')
    .trim()
    .escape()
    .not()
    .isEmpty()
    .withMessage('Phone can not be empty!')
    .bail()
    .isMobilePhone()
    .withMessage('Must be a phone number.')
    .bail(),
  check('email')
    .trim()
    .normalizeEmail()
    .not()
    .isEmpty()
    .withMessage('Invalid email address!')
    .bail(),
  check('note')
    .exists()
    .trim()
    .escape()
    .not()
    .isEmpty()
    .withMessage('Message can not be empty!')
    .bail(),
  check('botCheck')
    .isIn(["on"])
    .withMessage("Bot Check Failed")
    .bail(),
  function (req, res, next) {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    next();
  },
];
```

It is supposed to hand off errors to this ajax call:

```
const form = document.getElementById('contact-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const formData = new FormData(form);

  fetch('/contact/', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      mode: 'cors',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    })
    .then((response) => {
      response.json();
    })
    .then((response) => {
      // handle errors
      if (response.errors) {
        response.errors.forEach(({ msg }) => {
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += `<p class="note note-danger">${msg}</p>`
        });
        return;
      }
      // If mail was sent successfully, reset all elements with attribute 'name'
      const values = document.querySelectorAll('[name]');
      values.forEach( value => {
        value.textContent = '';
      });

      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = `<p class="note note-success">${response.msg}</p>`;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += `<p class="note note-danger">${err}</p>`
    })
    .finally(()=> {
      setTimeout(()=> {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = '';
      }, 2000)
    })
});
```

The start of the form has the right HTMl elements:
`<form id="contact-form" class="needs-validation" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">`

I can not get it past the 400 error that says "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'errors')". I am not sure if it's my server side validation in express-validator or the AJAX call that is incorrect.

Comment: Why are you sending form data with an explicitly JSON content type?

Comment: I have found that is usually the best way to get errors handled faster and it has worked well for me in the past. Is there something wrong with how its being sent?

Comment: Well form data and JSON are not the same format at all, but that's irrelevant to your problem - it's nothing to do with whether or how the server is validating the request or even how exactly it's responding, think about why `response` would be `undefined` where you're trying to access its `errors`.

Comment: Ok, so I can see the payload has the right fields. So that would mean the error is in my validator

Comment: That doesn't make sense as a theory. We can't rule out errors in the validator but that wouldn't cause the specific error you're asking about. Lint your code - [`promise/always-return`](https://github.com/eslint-community/eslint-plugin-promise/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/always-return.md).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I realized after looking back that it was the middleware that step 1 of the problem and then the Ajax handle I was using was formatted incorrectly to handle the response.

The correct Middleware should be:

```
module.exports = [
body("name")
  .trim()
  .notEmpty().withMessage('Name is required.')
  .isAlpha('en-US', {ignore: '\s'}).withMessage('Name can only have letters.')
  .bail(),

body("email")
  .trim()
  .notEmpty().withMessage('Email is required.')
  .isEmail().withMessage('Invalid email address.')
  .bail(),

body("phone")
  .trim()
  .notEmpty().withMessage('Phone number is required.')
  .isMobilePhone('en-US').withMessage("Please make sure it is a valid phone number")
  .bail(),

body("note")
  .trim()
  .notEmpty().withMessage('Message is required.')
  .bail(),

body("botCheck").isIn(["on"]).withMessage("Bot Check Failed"),


  function (req, res, next) {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    console.log("Validation Result:", errors); 
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
       
    }
    next();
  },
];
```

Then the AJAX to handle that response should be:

```
const form = document.getElementById('contact-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const formData = new FormData(form);
  for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
      console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
  }
  console.log(formData);  // Log form data

  fetch('/contact', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    mode: 'cors'
  })
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();  // Otherwise, proceed as usual
  })
  .then((response) => {
    // handle errors
    if (response.errors) {
      response.errors.forEach(({ msg }) => {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += `<p class="note note-danger">${msg}</p>`;
      });
      return;
    }
    // If mail was sent successfully, reset all elements with attribute 'name'
    const values = document.querySelectorAll('[name]');
    values.forEach(value => {
      value.textContent = '';
    });
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = `<p class="note note-success">${response.msg}</p>`;
    // Clear the form
    form.reset();
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += `<p class="note note-danger">${err}</p>`;
  })
  .finally(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = '';
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

I realize now that the 400 error was due to malformed express-validator code and I just needed to process the formData in the Ajax and it worked perfectly.

Thanks for the help.